# From Loader to Bitmap AS3 Flex

Tags: facebook, actionscript-3, apache-flex, bitmap, loader

i'm trying to load images from Facebook Albums to my flex app, this is the code called when i click on a FB image:

```
        private var loaderFB:Loader;
        private var immCaricata:Bitmap = new Bitmap();

        //Function where i pass the url of the FB image clicked
        private function getFBImage(src:String):void{
            var request:URLRequest;
            loaderFB=new Loader();              
            request=new URLRequest(src);
            loaderFB.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE,onCompleteFBget);
            loaderFB.load(request);
        }

        private function onCompleteFBget(event:Event):void {
            var bitmap_dataFB:BitmapData = new BitmapData(640, 480);
            bitmap_dataFB.draw(loaderFB.content);
            immCaricata = new Bitmap(bitmap_dataFB);
            displayOut.addChild(immCaricata);
        }
```

it doesn't work!

If i pass

```
displayOut.addChild(loaderFB); //instead displayOut.addChild(immCaricata);
```

It works like a charm!

My problem is that i need to pass loader content to that bitmap (immCaricata) cause i use it in different other functions.

I tried different solution, but probably i do some mistakes somewhere.

Could you please help me? Hope is all clear.
Thank you so much

**EDIT:**

The problem was not the syntax but the security policy file, i had to add it:

in **init** function:

```
Security.loadPolicyFile("http://graph.facebook.com/crossdomain.xml");
Security.loadPolicyFile("http://profile.ak.fbcdn.net/crossdomain.xml");
```

and then where i load the image

```
            loaderFB=new Loader();              
            request=new URLRequest(src);
            loaderFB.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE,onCompleteFBget);
            var lc:LoaderContext = new LoaderContext();
            lc.checkPolicyFile = true;
            loaderFB.load(request,lc);
            controlloImm = true;
```

Hope is clear and hope it helps someone else. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
private var loaderFB:Loader;
private var immCaricata:Bitmap;

//Function where i pass the url of the FB image clicked
private function getFBImage(src:String):void{
    var request:URLRequest;
    loaderFB=new Loader();              
    request=new URLRequest(src);
    loaderFB.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE,onCompleteFBget);
    loaderFB.load(request);
}

private function onCompleteFBget(event:Event):void {

    immCaricata = event.target.content as Bitmap;
    displayOut.addChild(immCaricata);
}
```

Try this if you dont wanna change the loaded image size, hope this will help

Comment: Thanks for your answer, i already tried this solution and it doesn't work.. i really can't understand why. Maybe the problem is in another part of code.. :/

Comment: is there any errors coming up ? some thing like sand box security violation ?